# Is it possible to optimize this jQuery

Tags: jquery, optimization

with my minimal knowledge about jQuery I somehow got this working - its a function that switches layout grid-/listview..

I would like to know if this can be improved in some way:

```
    $('span').on('click',function(e) {
     if ($(this).hasClass('gridview')) {
       $('div[id^="block"]').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
            $('span.gridview').addClass('active');
            $('span.listview').removeClass('active');
        }

     else if($(this).hasClass('listview')) {
       $('div[id^="block"]').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
            $('span.listview').addClass('active');
            $('span.gridview').removeClass('active');
        }
});
```

The part below where active state is set/removed on the buttons, doesnt look like smart code.. but it works :)
- Is there a better way to remove/add the class?

```
            $('span.gridview').addClass('active');
            $('span.listview').removeClass('active');
```

Any comments are much appreciated

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8L8SN/

Comment: you can use `.toggleClass()` reference [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't actually need that `if` and the following will be enough:

```
$('div[id^="block"]').toggleClass('list').toggleClass('grid');
$('span.gridview').toggleClass('active');
$('span.listview').toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: thanks, that removed more than 50%... And I guess that less if/then/else is some kind of a performance boost?

Comment: that's a very minor performance improvement - more important is that code is less verbose

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('span.gridview').toggleClass('active');
```